# Why do I get a "You were removed" message in inactive groups?

Tags: whatsapp

In some of the inactive groups, I see a message that says "you were removed," but I can see other people that are still in that group.  I just can't send messages anymore.

I know that this is different from "xyz removed you" where xyz can be one of the admins.  I am assuming that WhatsApp removed me from these groups where it says "you were removed."

What could be the reason for WhatsApp removing users from groups?

Comment: I don't know that we'll be able to speak to the "Why" of the situation.

Comment: If you were removed, how are you able to see other members in the group?

Comment: no idea, I am able to see others in those groups.